# $A$ is a commutative ring, $P$ is a prime ideal. Prove $A_P$ is local ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Question: Suppose $A$ is a commutative ring, $P$ is a prime ideal. Prove $A_P$ is local ring.

I have no idea how to construct the unique maximal ideal.

Comment: Take a peek at $\;pA_P\;$...or at **any** decent commutative algebra book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Book: "*Steps in Commutative Algebra*" by "*R.Y. Sharp*"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$, and let $I\subset R$ an ideal. If all the elements in $R\setminus I$ are invertible in $R$ then $R$ is local and $I$ is its unique maximal ideal.

Comment: Do u mean I is the set of all no unity? And how to get it?

Comment: Look at the definition of $A_P$ and make your guess!

Comment: is it $S^{-1}(P)$?